# How to use Jquery to reset count when multiple elements are deleted?

Tags: jquery, html, counter, dynamic-forms

Apologize ahead of time if I submitted this question incorrectly.  First question I have had large amounts of code to accompany it.

How can I reset a count variable and reassign that number to the respective fields when a group of elements is deleted?  I understand through the fiddle below how to do it if just one field is involved but not sure how to accomplish this same thing when multiple fields are together.

I have been learning a lot about Jquery but still finding myself encountering obstacles that leave me without answers.  Going off of this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5gxjmss/8/)

```
    <h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>

    function resetIndexes(){
    var j = 1;   
    $('.p_scnt').each(function(){
        if( j > 1){
        $(this).attr('name', 'p_scnt_' + j);
            $(this).attr('placeholder', 'Input Value'+j);
        }   
        j++;    
    });
}


$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents .p_scnt').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
        i = $('#p_scents .p_scnt').size() + 1;   
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" class="p_scnt" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value'+i+'" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#p_scents').on('click', '.remScnt', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    resetIndexes();
            }
            return false;
    });



});
```

I have reworked it to show what I am asking.  I understand how this works with one field but in my case, I have a group of inputs that need created with each other and deleted as a whole.  I cannot seem to find the correct method to keep the same function as shown in the first example.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

The reworked version.

```js
function resetIndexes(){
    var j = 1;   
    $('.p_scnt').each(function(){
        if( j > 1){
        $(this).attr('name', 'p_scnt_' + j);
            $(this).attr('placeholder', 'Input Value'+j);
        }   
        j++;    
    });
}


$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents .p_scnt').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
        i = $('#p_scents .p_scnt').size() + 1;   
        $('<p><input type="text" size="20" class="Parent" name="Parent_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value'+i+'" /><input type="text" size="20" class="Child" name="Child_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value'+i+'" /><input type="text" size="20" class="Grandchild" name="Grandchild_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value'+i+'" /><a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#p_scents').on('click', '.remScnt', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    resetIndexes();
            }
            return false;
    });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <input type="text" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="Parent" value="" placeholder="Parent" />
        <input type="text" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="Child" value="" placeholder="Child" />
        <input type="text" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="Grandchild" value="" placeholder="Grandchild" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hit the `<>` snippet editor to show the issue here

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your issue.

Comment: If you need to dynamically add a new input with the option to remove and fix the count used to number the elements, the first JSFiddle demonstrates it perfectly.  If you need to add a group of inputs with the same functionality and option to delete, the numbering gets all screwed up.

Comment: Do you really need counter at all? What is problem, actually? You can't remove right text field? (always last one is removed, as i can see)

Comment: I need to number the fields as in their ID and name.  When you run the Code Snippet and click add or remove, you can see the numbering gets out of order.  The first JSFiddle performs exactly as I am wanting it to but only when one field is dynamically added or removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this but one way is add a container element and then use that for your count. You could also probably divide the count of inputs by 3.

Here's an example with the first method. The inputs are wrapped with `<p class="input-wrap">` and it loops over those, finding inputs within and updating their name/input based on the count of the container.

Also splits the name of the original input elements on `_` so that the base names you used (like "Parent_") are preserved. You could do something similar for the `placeholder` attribute.

```js
function resetIndexes() {
  var j = 1, name, $this;
  
  // for each element on the page with the class .input-wrap
  $('.input-wrap').each(function() {
    if (j > 1) {
      // within each matched .input-wrap element, find each <input> element  
      $(this).find('input').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        name = $this.attr("name").split('_')[0];
        $(this).attr('name', name + '_' + j);
        $(this).attr('placeholder', 'Input Value ' + j);
      })
    }
    j++;
  });
}


$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var i;

  $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
    // instead of counting inputs, count the wrappers
    i = $('#p_scents .input-wrap').size() + 1;
    $('<p class="input-wrap"><input type="text" size="20" class="Parent" name="Parent_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value ' + i + '" /> <input type="text" size="20" class="Child" name="Child_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value ' + i + '" /> <input type="text" size="20" class="Grandchild" name="Grandchild_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value ' + i + '" /> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
  });

  $('#p_scents').on('click', '.remScnt', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
      $(this).parents('p').remove();
      resetIndexes();
    }
    return false;
  });



});
```

```css
* { font-family:Arial; }
h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
h2 a { color: #224f99; }
a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#802727; }
p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

input { padding:5px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; -web-kit-border-radius:4px; -khtml-border-radius:4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
  <p class="input-wrap">
    <input type="text" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="Parent" value="" placeholder="Parent" />
    <input type="text" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="Child" value="" placeholder="Child" />
    <input type="text" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="Grandchild" value="" placeholder="Grandchild" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, so with Jquery, and I assume any scripting to be specific, you can collectively group items by a parent element?

Comment: The parent/child relationship has to do with the DOM (seen here as nesting within the HTML). Javascript/jQuery have methods to traverse those relationships. I added a few comments to (hopefully) clarify what's happening.